# MySQL query by count

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've got a table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mailer__opens` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `idSubscriber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

I'm trying to build a query which returns only the results where the value in `idSubscriber` is repeated `5` or more times. (I hope I'm explaining this right).

EG, if the data in the table looked like this:

```
id | idSubscriber | date
------------------------------
1  | 00001        | 2010-01-01
2  | 00002        | 2010-01-02
3  | 00001        | 2010-01-05
4  | 00003        | 2010-01-26
5  | 00004        | 2010-02-14
6  | 00001        | 2010-02-28
7  | 00002        | 2010-03-05
8  | 00001        | 2010-03-06
9  | 00003        | 2010-03-10
10 | 00001        | 2010-04-01
11 | 00004        | 2010-05-06
12 | 00002        | 2010-05-08
```

I'd be interested in records `1`, `3`, `6`, `8` and `10`, because the `idSubscriber` `00001` has `5` or more records.

Can anyone provide me with a query that would do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To list the `idSubscriber` that has repeated five of more times you can use:

```
select idSubscriber 
from mailer__opens 
group by(idSubscriber) having count(*) >= 5;
```

To get the rows corresponding to such an `idSubscriber` you can use:

```
select * 
from mailer__opens 
where idSubscriber in 
  ( select idSubscriber 
    from mailer__opens 
    group by(idSubscriber) having count(*) >= 5 )
```

Comment: This won't work, it'll only give you one row back (all the rows for a given idSubscriber were collapsed into one per the GROUP BY), where he said he wants all those rows meeting that condition.

Answer (score 2):

You must use GROUP BY with a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT id FROM mailer__opens GROUP BY idSubscriber HAVING COUNT(id) >= 5
```

Comment: This won't work, it'll only give you one row back (all the rows for a given idSubscriber were collapsed into one per the GROUP BY), where he said he wants all those rows meeting that condition.

Comment: right, the solution I would have given has been also given by codaddict anyways, so I won't repeat it here

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the different idSubscriber values:

```
SELECT idSubscriber
FROM `mailer__opens` 
GROUP BY idSubscriber
HAVING count( * ) >=5
```

For the given dataset, this will fetch only one value: 1

Then you need to select all rows where the idSubscriber is equal to those values. Therefore, your final query becomes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mailer__opens
WHERE idsubscriber
IN (
    SELECT idSubscriber
    FROM `mailer__opens` 
    GROUP BY idSubscriber
    HAVING count( * ) >=5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM mailer__opens WHERE idSubscriber IN (SELECT idSubscriber FROM mailer__opens GROUP BY idSubscriber HAVING COUNT(id) >= 5)
```